# User save not saving with no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I have the following code for updating todos:

```
router.post('/edit/todo', function(req, res) {
  var post = req.body,
  newTitle = post.title,
  newDetails = post.details.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),
  // _id = post._id;
  index = post.index;

  console.log('req.user.todos[index] = ' + JSON.stringify(req.user.todos[index])); // old details

  req.user.todos[index].title = newTitle;
  req.user.todos[index].details = newDetails;

  req.user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    else {
      console.log('req.user.todos[index] = ' + JSON.stringify(req.user.todos[index]));    // new details
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var todos = req.user.todos; // old details
}
```

Here is the user schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true 
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    // keeps the tasks like homework and projects
    // each todo is made of a title, and details
    todos: [],

    // keeps the test
    // each test is made of a subject and a date
    // each date is made up of a month and a day
    tests: [],

    // keeps the schedule 
    // used by tomorrow tile
    schedule: { },

    // links for school related sites
    // each link is made up of a name and an href
    links: []
});
```

This is really weird because in the saving stage it goes through with no errors, and shows the new details, but it seems like it doesn't actually save the user.
Also, I have almost the same thing for creating todos (just with `push` instead of putting values) and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't define what the `todo` array contains in your schema, you need to tell Mongoose when you've modified the data within its elements by calling [`markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified):

```
req.user.todos[index].title = newTitle;
req.user.todos[index].details = newDetails;
req.user.markModified('todos');
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for two days now!